# Image not rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am looping through an API and collecting the product name and image url then displaying the information through props. The loop works fine and the product ame is displaying. However, the images are not rendering. Even when I copy and paste the image url, it still does not render. When I insert any random image url from the web, it displays. It is just images from this API.

Here is one of the image urls I am trying to display: `images.asos-media.com/products/converse-chuck-taylor-all-star-ox-national-park-sneakers-in-green/200520115-1-green`. When I put it straight in my chrome browser, the image loads. If someone can get this image to display in react, please show me how. Alternatively, here's a snippet of my code. Thanks in advance!

```
const Products = ({title, image}) => {
    return(
       <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <img src={image} alt="" />
        </div>              
    )
}
```

Comment: console.log(image). Is that what you expect?

Comment: Have you tried adding https:// in front of the url?

Comment: try to add `https://` in front of the image.

Comment: You need to show where your passing the image down the issue is likely in the parent component

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use the full url:

`https://images.asos-media.com/products/converse-chuck-taylor-all-star-ox-national-park-sneakers-in-green/200520115-1-green`

If that doesn't fix it, F12 and check for error messages in the console.